# How can I get a boost::function (or other generic function wrapper) that returns itself?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, fsm

I've recently become enamored with the simplicity of Erlang's actor-based concurrency model, and am playing around with ideas for implementing some parts of it in C++.  Along these lines, I also like the idea of implementing a finite state machine as a collection of functions representing states, where transitions are made by tail-calling from one function to the next.

I'd like to try something similar in C++.  But a naive implementation of this is likely to run into the fact that tail calling in my compiler (GCC 4.1 with `-O0`) will eventually cause a stack overflow.  So instead, what I'd like to do is have each state/function return a functor (the next state to enter), and have an underlying loop which just sequentially calls a functor, then calls the functor thus returned, then calls the functor thus returned, etc.  Something like:

```
typedef ... context_t;

// A statefunctor is a functor which takes a context_t and 
// returns a statefunctor
//
// FIXME: of course, this typedef won't compile.
typedef boost::function<statefunctor (context_t& )> statefunctor;

// NULL boost::function<> represents the exit condition.
static const statefunctor EXIT_FSM;

// primary loop which runs the FSM
void run_fsm(context_t& ctx, statefunctor initial_state)
{
    while (initial_state)
    {
        initial_state=initial_state(boost::ref(ctx));
    }
}

// states 'foo', 'bar', and 'baz';
statefunctor foo(context_t& ctx);
statefunctor bar(context_t& ctx, int inval);
statefunctor baz(context_t& ctx);

// State 'foo'
statefunctor foo(context_t& ctx)
{
    // act somehow on the external context
    int magic_number_1=ctx.get_magic_number();
    int magic_number_2=ctx.get_magic_number();

    // Always transition to 'bar'
    return boost::bind(&bar, _1, magic_number_1-magic_number_2);
}

// State 'bar'
statefunctor bar(context_t& ctx, int inval)
{
    inval+=ctx.get_magic_number(); // Act on external context somehow

    // transition to foo or baz
    if (inval>0) { return &foo; }
    else { return &baz; }
}

// State 'baz'
statefunctor baz(context_t& ctx)
{
    // Transition to foo or exit
    if (ctx.get_magic_number()==5) {return EXIT_FSM;}
    else {return &foo;}
}

int main()
{
    context_t ctx;
    // start the state machine in state 'foo'
    run_fsm(ctx, &foo);
}
```

So, my question is, how do I define `statefunctor`?  In particular, I want it to be capable of holding arbitrary functors (like `boost::bind(...)` might create), and not just function pointers.

**NOTE:** I'm using `boost::bind`, `boost::function`, `boost::ref` instead of their `std::` counterparts because I'm stuck using GCC 4.1, which has no support for C++11.  Solutions valid in C++03 are appreciated ;-).

Comment: Only semi-related, but the C functions `longjmp` and `setjmp` are used to do this sort of non-stack-based function calling. It is a common mechanism for implementing coroutines, for example.

Comment: Clarified the title on (what I think) is the focus of the question, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Rook: Only if you're suicidally inclined.

Comment: Have you looked at [libcppa](https://github.com/Neverlord/libcppa), a C++11 actor library? It provides various types of actors, including a context-switching one based on Boost Context.

Comment: After he specifies no C++11? Nais.

Comment: @Xeo: I'm not married to using `boost::function<>`, which your edit of my title implies.  Using a common library instead of writing the whole template metaprogramming mess myself would be nice, though.

Comment: @Rook: that sounds sort of scary in C++ (if maybe not so much in C).  Wouldn't playing around with the stack like that tend to interfere with RAII and exception handling?

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin, C++11 is out of scope for my current effort. But I do appreciate the reference, I hadn't found it in my previous searching. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly do this through a `typedef`, but you can wrap the `boost::function` in a struct / class (thanks to [@R. Martinho Fernandes](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5253400#5253400) for making me have this insight):

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

typedef int context_t;

struct statefunctor
  : boost::function<statefunctor(context_t&)>
{
  typedef boost::function<statefunctor(context_t&)> base_type;
  statefunctor() : base_type(){}
  template<class F>
  statefunctor(F f) : base_type(f){}
};
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/68cc68c988efc0d4bb8390708a4b8c3b)

Comment: This is similar to what I'd come up with so far, but much nicer. (rubber duck problem solving:http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html).  I'll probably accept this if something better doesn't come along.

Comment: Does the forwarding constructor in your `struct statefunctor` incur an additional copy of the functor F?

Comment: @Managu: Yeah, but functors are copied everywhere in C++ and expected to be rather lightweight (a `std::function` for example only has 12 bytes or so).

Answer (score 3):

This is impossibru. The type would be infinite, and the problem is identical to the one you would encounter defining a function pointer that returns itself. The only way to do this is to manually write your own function object with an operator(), this can return `*this`, and chain`()` calls. You can also use operator chaining in other ways, like you can see in `std::cout`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The problem is that the definition of the returned type would have to be recursive and that is not possible.